# Voluntaries to get rid of Covid-19

Tags: covid-19, infection, coronavirus, cure

What are the requirements for anyone who wants to come to the USA as a volunteer to find a cure to Coronavirus ?
Im not afraid if i get infected or die. I just want to do something that is worth sacrificing life.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about medical sciences

Comment: Have you googled something?

Comment: "Im not afraid if i get infected" with all respect but I think you don't know what you are talking about. Do you have any idea of how much one might end up suffering, thanks to this virus, in the worst case scenario?

Comment: Please stay at home, if you can.

Comment: Why go to the USA? There’s lots of other places working on this. I suspect if you have to ask you’re not qualified to do the job.